# random java.io.FileNotFoundException jobcache error on EMR with MrJob

Tags: python, hadoop, emr, mrjob

I am using MrJob and trying to run a Hadoop job on Elastic Map Reduce which keeps crashing at random.

The data looks like this (tab separated):

```
279391888       261151291       107.303163      35.468534
279391888       261115099       108.511726      35.503008
279391888       261151290       104.881560      35.278487
279391888       261151292       109.732004      35.659141
279391888       261266862       108.507754      35.434581
279391888       1687590146      59.118796       19.931201
279391888       269450882       58.909985       19.914108
```

And the underlying MapReduce is very simple:

```
from mrjob.job import MRJob
import numpy as np

class CitypathsSummarize(MRJob):
  def mapper(self, _, line):
    orig, dest, minutes, dist = line.split()
    minutes = float(minutes)
    dist = float(dist)
    if minutes < .001:
      yield "crap", 1
    else:
      yield orig, dist/minutes

  def reducer(self, orig, speeds):
    speeds = list(speeds)
    mean = np.mean(speeds)
    yield orig, mean

if __name__ == "__main__":
  CitypathsSummarize.run()
```

When I run it, I use the following command, using the default mrjob.conf (my keys are set in the environment):

```
$ python summarize.py -r emr --ec2-instance-type c1.xlarge --num-ec2-instances 4 s3://citypaths/chicago-v4/ > chicago-v4-output.txt
```

When I run it on small data sets, it finishes fine. When I run it on the whole data corpus (about 10GiB worth), I get errors like this (but not at the same point each time!):

```
Probable cause of failure (from s3://mrjob-093c9ef589d9f262/tmp/logs/j-KCPTKZR5OX6D/task-attempts/attempt_201301211911_0001_m_000151_3/syslog):
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt2/var/lib/hadoop/mapred/taskTracker/jobcache/job_201301211911_0001/attempt_201301211911_0001_m_000018_4/output/spill0.out
(while reading from s3://citypaths/chicago-v4/1613640660)
Terminating job flow: j-KCPTKZR5OX6D
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "summarize.py", line 32, in <module>
    CitypathsSummarize.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mrjob/job.py", line 545, in run
    mr_job.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mrjob/job.py", line 561, in execute
    self.run_job()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mrjob/job.py", line 631, in run_job
    runner.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mrjob/runner.py", line 490, in run
    self._run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mrjob/emr.py", line 1048, in _run
    self._wait_for_job_to_complete()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mrjob/emr.py", line 1830, in _wait_for_job_to_complete
    raise Exception(msg)
Exception: Job on job flow j-KCPTKZR5OX6D failed with status SHUTTING_DOWN: Shut down as step failed
Probable cause of failure (from s3://mrjob-093c9ef589d9f262/tmp/logs/j-KCPTKZR5OX6D/task-attempts/attempt_201301211911_0001_m_000151_3/syslog):
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt2/var/lib/hadoop/mapred/taskTracker/jobcache/job_201301211911_0001/attempt_201301211911_0001_m_000018_4/output/spill0.out
(while reading from s3://citypaths/chicago-v4/1613640660)
```

I've run this twice; the first time it died after 45 minutes, and this time it died after four hours. It has died on different files both times. I've checked both of the files it died on and neither has any problems.

Somehow it's failing to find the spill files that it writes, which is confusing me.

EDIT:

I ran the job again, and it died again after a few hours, this time with a different error message.

```
Probable cause of failure (from s3://mrjob-093c9ef589d9f262/tmp/logs/j-3GGW2TSIKKW5R/task-attempts/attempt_201301310511_0001_m_001810_0/syslog):
Status Code: 403, AWS Request ID: 9E9E748A55BC6A58, AWS Error Code: RequestTimeTooSkewed, AWS Error Message: The difference between the request time and the current time is too large., S3 Extended Request ID: Ky+HVYZ8RsC3l5f9N3LTwyorY9bbqEnc4tRD/r/xfAHYP/eiQrjjcpmIDNY2eoDo
(while reading from s3://citypaths/chicago-v4/1439606131)
```

Comment: Can you show the command line  how you run your job with MRJob?